# How to concatenate arrays with different size in list or array?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I have multiple arrays with different size such as `m0xn0xk0, m1xn1xk1, m2xn2xk2...`. I am looking for a method to concatenate them into a single array `A_concate` that can be accessed in future based on the index. It likes

```
A_concate [0]=a_0 # size of m0xn0xk0
A_concate [1]=a_1 # size of m1xn1xk1
...
```

Do we have any way to do it in python? Thanks all

Comment: When you say array do you mean numpy arrays? Numpy arrays have to be rectangular so you can only put together blocks in a way that you end up with a multidimensional rectangle.

Comment: Yes. There are numpy array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do with this structure. For instance, if there is some value unique to `m0xn0xk0, m1xn1xk1, m2xn2xk2...` that you want to index by then you would use a dictionary like this:

```
A_concate = {}
A_concate[some_key] = m0xn0xk0
A_concate[some_other_key] = m1xn1xk1
```

and then you could access them using the key values. On the other hand, if you just want all these lists to live on the same object and you're only going to iterate over them, using a list is fine:

```
def listify(*args):
    return list(args)

A_concate = listify(m0xn0xk0, m1xn1xk1, m2xn2xk2, ...)
```

Finally, if you just want all the values of these objects in the same place, then you could just concatenate them into one list:

```
def flatten(*lists):
    a = []
    for l in lists:
        a.extend(l)
    return a

A_concate = flatten(m0xn0xk0, m1xn1xk1, m2xn2xk2, ...)
```

It just depends on what you want to do with it.

Comment: Hi. If I want to concatenate them in loop. How can I modify your code? I have write a script at here but it does not show correct dimension https://repl.it/repls/LightGrotesqueCodeview

Comment: Could you look at my issue? It is missing one dims

Comment: Of course it is. `extend` unpacks your list and adds each element to the list you're extending

Comment: In my code, I only can show dim (4,5) and missing the dim (3). Could you tell me how should I modify it to obtain the shape of A[0] is (3,4,5)

Comment: In that case you'd want to use `add` instead of `extend`

Comment: This is error `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'add'
`. You mean append

Comment: @MoonLee Sorry about that, I've been doing a lot of C# lately so I got turned around. Use `append` instead :)

Answer (score 1):

If that is all you want to do then why not just put them in a list?

You could use

```
A_concate = [a_0, a_1, a_2,..., a_n]
```

If you really want to use an array you could use

```
import numpy as np
A_concate = np.array([a_0, a_1, a_2,..., a_n])
```

The above will give you an array of objects. Where each entry is an array. You won't have the full functionality to slice across the internal arrays but it depends on what you want to do

Here is a minimal example of the above

```
import numpy as np
a_0 = np.arange(9)
a_1 = np.arange(10)
a_2 = np.arange(16)
A_concate = np.array([a_0, a_1, a_2])
```

EDIT

Add another example to show it works more generally than for 1D arrays

```
import numpy as np
a_0 = np.random.normal(0,1,size=(3,4,5,))
a_1 = np.random.normal(0,1,size=(4,5,6,))
a_2 = np.random.normal(0,1,size=(35,19,97,))
a_3 = np.random.normal(0,1,size=(2,6,14,22,89))
A_concate = np.array([a_0, a_1, a_2, a_3])
```

Comment: Sorry. there arrays have different size. Could you show the example with size of 3x4x5 for a_0, 4x5x6 for a_1...

Comment: Yeh, it will work just the same with your arrays. For example here is one where I concatenate 3 random arrays with shapes 3x4x5, 4x5x6 and 35x19x97. EDIT. I can't get it to display nice in the comments here so I will add it to the answer above.